# Tighter upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^kA_i\log(\frac{A_i}{e})$

Tags: co.combinatorics, arithmetic-progression, arithmetic-functions

What is the tightest upper bound one can obtain for the following expression

$$\sum_{i=1}^kA_i\log(\frac{A_i}{e})$$ subject to $\sum_{i = 1}^k A_i = C$ in terms of $C$ and $k$?

A very loose upper bound for this expression is $C\log(\frac{C}{e})$. Can we do better than this?

Comment: Something's wrong here: when all $A_i$ approach $0$ except for $A_1$, then the sum converges to $C \log(C/e)$, which is greater than your upper bound.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers tell you that this is maximized when $A_i = C/k.$

Comment: @IgorRivin does not that *minimize* the function? I mean, $x\log(x/e)$ is convex, not concave.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko very true. I guess I will have to answer the question then :(

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki you are correct. My given upper bound was assuming $A_i \geq 1$ which is not in general true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gradient of your function is $(\log A_1, \dotsc, \log A_n).$ The function is convex, and so the minimum can be seen, by Lagrange multipliers to occur when all of the $A_i$ are equal (to $C/k$). So, the minimum value of the function is 
$$C \log\left(\frac{C}{ke}\right).$$

On the other hand, the maximum must occur on the boundary, which is to say, when some of the $A_i$ are $0.$ It is clear that in fact for a maximum, *all but one* $A_i$ are $0,$ on which case (since $\lim_{x\to 0} x \log x = 0$), the value is $C \log\frac{C}{e}.$.

Comment: Just a comment: This is a typical problem that chooses a discrete distribution supported on simplex which maximizes the entropy w.r.t. the discrete uniform.